# Git and TortoiseSVN, how do i undo my changes in local repository without cloning the remote repo again

Tags: git, svn, github

i have the below commands to update my repository, which will update my library using TortoiseSVN and source with Git.

But i want to undo all the changes i made and replace it with what's there in the master repo.

```
cd lib\win64_vc12
svn update
cd ..\..\project
git pull --rebase
git submodule foreach git pull --rebase origin master
```

I researched and found its

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

but i am not sure,how i do it with this,i am new to git, i don't want to re-clone the repo,as its huge.

Need your kind help,thank you

Abhijith

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
```

will reset you to the desired commit and all the changes will be lost so be care full while doing it.

Comment: but can i not specify the master branch instead of the hash value of the commit ?

Comment: why will you reset to a branch you can only reset to a specific commit in a specific branch.

Answer (score 0):

> But i want to undo all the changes i made and replace it with what's there in the master repo.

The simple way is simply to delete the "dirty" branch and checkout the new branch from your local repo

```
# delete the local master branch
git branch -D master

# checkout the latest branch without the need to clone the repository again
git checkout origin/masetr
```

---

#### ***`What else can you do to fix it?`***

You have to set up your HEAD to point to a new (or old) commit.
The above post will show you and will teach you what to do and will show you few options.

If you want to ***`undo`*** your changes. Do do so you have several options, which you can read about in details in here:

**[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)**

It will explain in details what to do in each option.